# Unexpected syntax error in parser. Cannot find LPAREN

Tags: python-3.x, ply

Im having issues executing code on the parser I made and im getting

```
Syntax error found!
(
```

This is my code

```py
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc
import sys

# Create a list to hold all of the token names
tokens = [
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'INT',
    'FLOAT',
    'PLUS',
    'MINUS',
    'MULTIPLY',
    'DIVIDE',
    'PRINT',
    'STRING',
]

# Use regular expressions to define what each token is
t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_MINUS = r'\-'
t_MULTIPLY = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE = r'\/'
t_PRINT = r'print'
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'

# Ply's special t_ignore variable allows us to define characters the lexer will ignore.
# We're ignoring spaces.
t_ignore = r' '

# More complicated tokens, such as tokens that are more than 1 character in length
# are defined using functions.
# A float is 1 or more numbers followed by a dot (.) followed by 1 or more numbers again.

def t_STRING(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    t.value = str(t.value)
    return t

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'\d+\.\d+'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

# An int is 1 or more numbers.
def t_INT(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

# Skip the current token and output 'Illegal characters' using the special Ply t_error function.
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal characters!")
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()

# Ensure our parser understands the correct order of operations.
# The precedence variable is a special Ply variable.
precedence = (

    ('left', 'LPAREN', 'RPAREN'),
    ('left', 'PLUS', 'MINUS'),
    ('left', 'MULTIPLY', 'DIVIDE')

)

# Define our grammar. We allow expressions, var_assign's and empty's.

# Expressions are recursive.
def p_expression(p):
    '''
    expression : expression MULTIPLY expression
               | expression DIVIDE expression
               | expression PLUS expression
               | expression MINUS expression
    '''
    # Build our tree.
    if p[2] == '*':
        p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
    elif p[2] == '/':
        p[0] = p[1] / p[3]
    elif p[2] == '+':
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    elif p[2] == '-':
        p[0] = p[1] - p[3]

def p_expression_int_float(p):
    '''
    expression : INT
               | FLOAT
               | STRING
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_print(p):
  'statement : PRINT LPAREN STRING RPAREN'
  print(p[3])

# Output to the user that there is an error in the input as it doesn't conform to our grammar.
# p_error is another special Ply function.
def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error found!\n" + p.value)

def p_empty(p):
    '''
    empty :
    '''
    p[0] = None

# Build the parser
parser = yacc.yacc()
# Create the environment upon which we will store and retreive variables from.
env = {}
# The run function is our recursive function that 'walks' the tree generated by our parser.
def run(p):
    global env
    if type(p) == tuple:
        if p[0] == '+':
            return run(p[1]) + run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '-':
            return run(p[1]) - run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '*':
            return run(p[1]) * run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '/':
            return run(p[1]) / run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '=':
            env[p[1]] = run(p[2])
            return ''
        elif p[0] == 'var':
            if p[1] not in env:
                return 'Undeclared variable found!'
            else:
                return env[p[1]]
    else:
        return p

# Create a REPL to provide a way to interface with our calculator.
while True:
    try:
        s = input('>> ')
    except EOFError:
        break
    parser.parse(s)
```

As you can see LPAREN does exist but is raising syntax error in the parser. I dont know if this is a problem with my regex or my  code itself but this is really annoying and I've been trying to figure it out for a day now. Please help

Comment: You could help a lot by showing the exact inputs you have tried along with the precise results (rather than an informal description of what you think is transpiring). Copy and paste from your terminal, for example. (In the question, ***not*** as a comment.)

Comment: Having said that, your grammar only allows parentheses in print statements and statements aren't derivable from your start symbol afaics. So it's not that surprising that they produce syntax errors.

Comment: The comments in that code are useless at best. Most of them are incorrect since they apply to code which you didn't copy; the rest provide no useful information. Comments don't matter to the running of the code, of course, but there's no reason to waste space here by including misleading or redundant comments.